# convert Hindi text to UTF-16 format

Tags: java, character-encoding

I want to convert my Hindi input to UTF-16 format. That's why I convert my string to byte array using character set "UTF-16".

But it will replace my string with ?????.

Here is the code

```
String original = "गुणवत्ता"; 
        byte[] bytearr = original.getBytes("UTF-16");            
        String test= new String(bytearr,"UTF-16");
```

Comment: How exactly are you outputting the string? `System.out.println(test);`? Or some other way?

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for reply i'm using jdeveloper ide and debug the code to check the value and also written this statement System.out.println(test);

Comment: Have you tried UTF-8 instead?

Comment: yes, same output.

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode the converted string as follows:

```
String original = "गुणवत्ता"; 
byte[] bytearr = original.getBytes("UTF-16");            
String test= new String(bytearr,"UTF-16");
String encodedString = MimeUtility.encodeText(test, "utf-16", "B");
```

Comment: Hi Sujit, thanks for reply. i have tried this but same issue.

Comment: where exactly you are rendering this string?